# how to add (plus) to a cell using a textbox

Tags: excel, vb.net

i need to add a number to textbox for everytime a specific item that was used to a cell in excel using vb. For example, for everytime the word "Time" is selected from the combobox1, it must add 1 to cell B2. and if "Time" is selected again. it must add 1 again to cell B2. Then cell B2 must have "2" in it

ive tried this, but it doesnt seem to work:

```
Dim Scrap As String

        Scrap = ComboBox1.Text
        Select Case Scrap
            Case "Aluminium"
            worksheet2.Cells(4, 3) = +AmountBox.Text
            worksheet2.Cells(4, 4) = +KiloBox.Text
            worksheet2.Cells(4, 2) = +1 'adds 1 for each time this type of scrap is used
end select
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: ive tried using this code `worksheet2.Cells(4, 2) = +1 `

Comment: That won't work. Grab the value from the cell, put it in a variable and add 1 to it and then write that variable back to the cell

Comment: @Cal-cium could you possibily put that into code?

Comment: What happens in the line `worksheet2.Cells(4, 2) = +1`?

Comment: it overwrites the value in `worksheet2.cells(4, 2)`. So if "1" is already there, it will replace it with "1".

Comment: Yeah thats because the line you currently using is writing to that cell, try my answer and see if it works

Comment: it's the same with the other cells for each textboxs, it overwrites the values. Trying to find a way to "+" to the value that's already there

Comment: i tried `     Dim add1 As Integer 
                worksheet2.Cells(4, 2) = add1
                add1 = worksheet2.Cells(4, 2) + 1 `

Comment: I'm slightly confused, what you are trying to do. So far what i understand. you are trying to add 1 to a Cell if a condition is met. The code in your question isnt working because you are overwriting them with code you are think is adding one. I cant read your last comment, Can you separate them into separate code tags please.

Comment: `worksheet2.Cells(4, 2) = (worksheet2.Cells(4, 2).Value + 1)` This might work but its untested. I would try what i put in my answer if you havent

Comment: @Cal-cium that one works as well. I'll use that one instead, it's short and sweet

Comment: No problem, I'll add it to the answer so it has both :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim Temp as Integer = CInt(worksheet2.Cells(4, 2).Value)
Temp += 1
worksheet2.Cells(4, 2).Value = Temp
```

Try something like this

This as well can do it:

`worksheet2.Cells(4, 2) = (worksheet2.Cells(4, 2).Value + 1)`

Comment: i changed the "Cell" to "Cells", and now it works perfectly, it's adding 1 everytime the selected item is chosen. Thanks!